# Собственно вот игра крестики нолики с ботом. Проблема в том, что программа не прекращает выполнение на последнем 9м ходе

Tags: java

Проблема в том, что программа не замечает победу компьютера(если конечно поддаться, т.к. проиграть рандому не легко) и продолжает предлагать мне сделать ход. Также программа не заканчивается на последнем 9м ходе и упорно предлагает задать координаты. То есть работает корректно только если выйграть до последнего хода).

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static final char[][] gameTable = new char[][]{
            {'#', '#', '#'},
            {'#', '#', '#'},
            {'#', '#', '#'}
    };

    public static int moves = 1;
    static boolean gameContinues = true;
    static char winner = ' ';


    public static void showTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(gameTable[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void enemyMove() {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 3);


        while (gameTable[x][y] == 'O' || gameTable[x][y] == 'X') {
            x = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            y = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        }

        gameTable[x][y] = 'X';

        showTable();
        moves++;
        System.out.println("Ход № " + moves);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void yourMove() {

        boolean d = true;
        while (d == true) {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Ваш ход! Введите координату Х: ");
                int a = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                System.out.print("Ваш ход! Введите координату Y: ");
                int b = scanner.nextInt() - 1;


                if ((a >= 0 && a < 3) && (b >= 0 && b < 3) && (gameTable[b][a] != 'X') && (gameTable[b][a] != 'O')) {
                    gameTable[b][a] = 'O';
                    break;
                }


                while (a != 0 || a != 1 || a != 2 || b != 0 || b != 1 || b != 2) {

                    System.out.println("Нужно задать корректные координаты!");
                    System.out.println("Введите заново координату Х: ");
                    a = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                    System.out.println("Введите заново координату Y: ");
                    b = scanner.nextInt() - 1;

                    if (a >= 0 && a < 3 && b >= 0 && b < 3 && (gameTable[b][a] != 'X') && (gameTable[b][a] != 'O')) {
                        gameTable[b][a] = 'O';
                        d = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Вы ввели недопустимые символы!");
                continue;
            }
        }

        showTable();

        moves++;
        System.out.println("Ход № " + (moves-1));
        System.out.println();
    }



    public static void checkWin() {
            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                if (gameTable[n][0] == gameTable[n][1] && gameTable[n][1] == gameTable[n][2]
                        && gameTable[n][0] != '#') {
                    winner = gameTable[n][0];
                    gameContinues = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                if (gameTable[0][n] == gameTable[1][n] && gameTable[1][n] == gameTable[2][n]
                        && gameTable[0][n] != '#') {
                    winner = gameTable[0][n];
                    gameContinues = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (gameTable[0][0] == gameTable[1][1] && gameTable[1][1] == gameTable[2][2]
                    && gameTable[0][0] != '#') {
                winner = gameTable[0][0];
                gameContinues = false;
            }

            if (gameTable[0][2] == gameTable[1][1] && gameTable[1][1] == gameTable[2][0]
                    && gameTable[0][2] != '#') {
                winner = gameTable[0][2];
                gameContinues = false;
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        do {

            enemyMove();
            checkWin();

            yourMove();
            checkWin();
            if (moves>9){
                gameContinues=false;
                winner = ' ';
                break;
            }

        } while (gameContinues == true);

        if (gameContinues == false)
            if (winner == 'X') {
                System.out.println("Вы проиграли :(");
            } else if (winner == 'O') {
                System.out.println("Вы выйграли!");
            } else if (winner == ' ') {
                System.out.println("Ничья!");
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. У вас ходы нумеруются с 0, и девятый ход поэтому будет при moves равном 8. Таким образом надо изменить проверку, например так `if(moves-1 > 9)`
2. Очевидно проверку надо вынести в отдельный метод и проверять после хода каждого игрока.

   ```
   public static char getWinner() {            
       for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
           if (gameTable[n][0] == gameTable[n][1] && gameTable[n][1] == gameTable[n][2]
                   && gameTable[n][0] != '#') {
               return gameTable[n][0];                    
           }
       }

       for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
           if (gameTable[0][n] == gameTable[1][n] && gameTable[1][n] == gameTable[2][n]
                   && gameTable[0][n] != '#') {
               return gameTable[0][n];

           }
       }

      if (gameTable[0][0] == gameTable[1][1] && gameTable[1][1] == gameTable[2][2]
                   && gameTable[0][0] != '#') {
               return gameTable[0][0];                    
      }

      if (gameTable[0][2] == gameTable[1][1] && gameTable[1][1] == gameTable[2][0]
                   && gameTable[0][2] != '#') {
               return gameTable[0][2];                    
      }
      return ' ';
   }
   ```
3. Обратите внимание, как у вас выполнено прерывание игры. Вы делаете 4 проверки на победу, две из них в цикле `for`, и в случае победы везде делаете `break` полагая прервать ход игры. Но внутри циклов for вы лишь их и прервёте. Тут вам поможет изменить цикл с предусловием на с постусловием `do..while`.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       boolean gameContinues = true;
       char winner = ' ';

       do {
           enemyMove();
           winner = getWinner();
           if (winner != ' ') {
               gameContinues = false;                    
           }    
           if (gameContinues) {
               yourMove();
           }
           if (winner != ' ') {
               gameContinues = false;                    
           }    
           if(moves-1>9) {
               gameContinues = false;
           }
       } while (gameContinues)

       if (winner == 'X') {
          System.out.println("Вы проиграли :(");
       } else if (winner == 'O') {
           System.out.println("Вы выИграли!");
       } else if (winner == ' ') {
           System.out.println("Ничья!");
       }

   }
   ```

   Также цикл с постусловием поможет вам не дублировать генерацию случайных координат в методе хода компьютера.

   ```
   public static void enemyMove() {
      int x;
      int y;
      do {
          x = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
          y = (int) (Math.random() * 3)  ;
      } while (gameTable[x][y] != 'O' && gameTable[x][y] != 'X')
      gameTable[x][y] = 'X';

      showTable();
      moves++;
      System.out.println("Ход № " + moves);
      System.out.println();
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил нумерацию ходов. Теперь начинается с 1. Но если компьютер выигрывает, то все равно нужно сделать ход и только потом засчитывается поражение.

Comment: `enemyMove();
 yourMove();` Между ними проверку на выигрышную ситуацию

Comment: @Ibuprofenn, я вроде понял сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: @4per то есть если поменять с for на do while, то выгледить будет так:    do {
            if (gameTable[0][n] == gameTable[1][n] && gameTable[1][n] == gameTable[2][n]
                    && gameTable[0][n] != '#') {
                winner = gameTable[0][n];
                gameContinues = false;
                break;
            }
            n++;
        } while (n<3);

Comment: нет не `for` (цикл со счётчиком). поменять надо `while`(цикл с предусловием) на `do..while` в ходе игры и в генерации случайных координат. Тогда можно выбросить `break` из проверок диагоналей, в for-ax их логично оставить. Добавлю исправленный код в ответ.

Comment: @4per Поменял на do while. Пока вроде без изменений работает. Ну либо я снова что-то напутал)

Comment: @4per Спасибо большое за помощь. Скопировал код к себе. Выйгрыш бота происходит полностью корректно, а вот победа человека не совсем. После того, как появляется выйгрышная комбинация, копьютер ходит еще раз и только после этого засчитывается победа.

Comment: @4per Попробовал еще сделать ничью, игра все равно не прерывается почему то. Очень странно

Comment: @4per Еще раз спасибо за помощь, все работает!